# Multi-level dictionary creation

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, defaultdict

sample input in place of `separate_function`:

```
separate_function = [('primary_1', 'val_1'), ('primary_1', 'val_2'), ('primary_3', 'val_2')]
```

Expected output i.e. `my_dictionary`:

```
{
    "main": {
        "primary_1": [
            "val_1",
            "val_2"
        ],
        "primary_3": [
            "val_2"
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to create a dictionary, `my_dictionary` like above.

There are multiple keys like `"main"` in the expected output.  To reduce the complexity of the problem, I have hard-coded it.
There is a generator function on which I need to iterate over to create this format. Again for simplicity, I have shown that as a list of tuples. I have tried so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dictionary = defaultdict(dict)
for primary_var, value in separate_function:
    my_dictionary['main'][primary_var].append(value)
    # This would have worked if I have expected values as string 
    # rather than a list in that case I can write the above line like this:
    my_dictionary['main'][primary_var] = value
```

`try`, `except` can be used and if `KeyError` then assign first else append can be done, However, I am looking for a better clean solution. Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.setdefault` to initialize a new dict key with a new list:

```
my_dictionary = {'main': {}}
for k, v in separate_function:
    my_dictionary['main'].setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

`my_dictionary` would become:

```
{'main': {'primary_1': ['val_1', 'val_2'], 'primary_3': ['val_2']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `collections.defaultdict`.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
separate_function = [('primary_1', 'val_1'), ('primary_1', 'val_2'), ('primary_3', 'val_2')] 
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in separate_function:
    result[k].append(v)


my_dictionary = {"main": result}
print(my_dictionary)
```

**Output:**

```
{'main': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'primary_3': ['val_2'], 'primary_1': ['val_1', 'val_2']})}
```

---